# jq query to pull values from json file to create a listing

Tags: jq

Given this input small sample:

```
{
  "_format_version": "1.1",
  "_workspace": "test",
  "services": [
    {
      "connect_timeout": 60000,
      "host": "host-name-test.com",
      "name": "name-of-service",
      "path": "/test/oauthpass",
      "port": 777,
      "protocol": "http",
      "read_timeout": 1000,
      "retries": 1,
      "write_timeout": 1000,
      "routes": [
        {
          "hosts": [
            "Google.com"
          ],
          "name": "com.testing.active.oauth",
          "methods": [
            "POST"
          ],
          "paths": [
            "/vendors/otest/pass/?$"
          ],
          "path_handling": "v8",
          "preserve_host": false,
          "protocols": [
            "https"
          ],
          "regex_priority": 0,
          "strip_path": true,
          "https_redirect_status_code": 426,
          "request_buffering": true,
          "response_buffering": true
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

trying to get a listing from the data pulling certain values like the listing below:

```
host-name-test.com, Google.com, POST, HTTPS
```

the command that I have working so far is

```
cat /tmp/petecar.json | jq -r ' .services[] | .routes[] | ( .hosts[] + "/" + .paths[]) ' | more
```

but I can't access the values under services, please provide some sample on how to get the values

Comment: Your jq filter is valid (see the [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0mBESDidxz)), your JSON isn't. There's a array closing bracket `]` missing in the second-to-last line.

Comment: I had to change up the data to post and missed that bracket, but for the jq I need to add to it in order to get the values under services something like this - jq -r '.services[] | .host + " " | .routes[] | ( .hosts[] + "/" + .paths[])' /tmp/petecar.json  but I get errors in trying to figure out how to write the jq

Comment: It would help if you included the error message, so people can see what went wrong, and also the concrete expected output to that very command that failed, so people can try to correct/recreate what you intended to achieve. Without, people have to guess. Here's mine: Did you mean `.services[] | .host + " ", (.routes[] | ( .hosts[] + "/" + .paths[]))`? [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/8eDgVB4fqw)

Comment: Sorry about that, here is the command and error message I get

Comment: jq -r '.services[] | .host + " " + .routes[].hosts' /tmp/petecar.json
jq: error (at /tmp/petecar.json:21824): string ("host-name...) and array (["Google.c...) cannot be added

Answer (score 0):

`routes` has an array value and as such cannot be concatenated with a string. You can use [`join`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#join(str)) to turn that array into a single string:

```
jq -r '.services[] | .host + " " + (.routes[].hosts | join(","))'
```

Output:

```
host-name-test.com Google.com
```

---

Alternatively, using [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Stringinterpolation-(foo)) which will automatically serialize any values into their string representation:

```
jq -r '.services[] | "\(.host) \(.routes[].hosts)"'
```

Output:

```
host-name-test.com ["Google.com"]
```

---

`join` and string interpolation can be combined, giving you the identical output of the first command:

```
jq -r '.services[] | "\(.host) \(.routes[].hosts|join(","))"'
```